# Where am I going wrong with this Python script that uses the selenium and pyautogui libraries to automate Excel and Safari tasks?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, pyautogui

I'm having some trouble with a script that I bashed together. I feel like I'm going in the right direction with what I've cobbled together so far but my coding acumen isn't the best and I keep getting an error message that starts with: Traceback (most recent call last). I did enable remote automation on Safari so there's one thing that I got right.

The aim is to copy text from the currently selected cell in Excel, open a url in safari, paste the clipboard into a text input on that webpage, submit the form that contains said input, when the output appears in the form of a div with a class that is created the script should wait 1 second, then copy a value from a span in the output div, then open excel again, go right one cell (right arrow key), paste the clipboard, go down and left one cell (again with the arrow keys), then repeat for n times.

**Some background info**

- Running Python 3.11.1
- MacOS 13.0.1
- Installed the libraries by running the "pip3 install selenium" and "pip3 install pyautogui" command in the terminal

The Python script:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from pyautogui import press, typewrite
import time

# Open Safari and navigate to the URL

driver = webdriver.Safari()
driver.get("https://example.com")

# Find the input field and the submit button

email_input = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "form input")
submit_button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "form input\[type=submit\]")

for i in range(10):
# Copy the selected cell in Excel
press("cmd", "c")

    # Paste the email into the input field and submit the form
    email_input.send_keys("cmd", "v")
    submit_button.click()
    
    # Wait for the div to be created
    time.sleep(1)
    div = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.wrap div.checker")
    while div is None:
        div = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.wrap div.checker")
    
    # Wait for one second
    time.sleep(1)
    
    # Copy the content of the span
    span = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.checkerS span.value")
    span.click()
    press("cmd", "c")
    
    # Close the tab and open Excel
    press("cmd", "w")
    typewrite("Microsoft Excel")
    press("enter")
    
    # Press the right arrow key, paste the clipboard, and move to the next cell
    press("right")
    press("cmd", "v")
    press("down")
    press("left")

# Close the browser

driver.quit()
```

The error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jamesthompson/Desktop/script.py", line 16, in <module>
    press("cmd", "c")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyautogui/__init__.py", line 598, in wrapper
    returnVal = wrappedFunction(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyautogui/__init__.py", line 1606, in press
    for i in range(presses):
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Comment: Edit your question and post the full error message (as text), properly formatted.

Comment: My $0.02... don't automate Excel. Instead read/write to a CSV file then once the automation is complete, you can open the CSV in Excel and use Excel's full functionality without all the extra complexity of having to automate it.